# Why are my launchd job's EnvironmentVariables not being set in OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, plist, osx-yosemite, launchd

I have a plist like the following:

```
{
    "EnvironmentVariables" : {
        "PATH": "/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin",
        "TEST" : "some value"
    },
    "WorkingDirectory" : "/Users/me",
    "Program": "/usr/bin/printenv",
    "StandardErrorPath" : "myjob.log",
    "StandardOutPath" : "myjob.log",
    "Label" : "com.mydomain.MyJob",
    "RunAtLoad" : true
}
```

compiling it with:

```
plutil -convert binary1 -r myjob.plist.json -o myjob.plist
```

loading it with:

```
launchctl load myjob.plist
```

When I look at the results in myjob.log it doesn't contain any of the environment variables I defined in the plist. This is a problem for me because I can't seem to set the path to include things like /bin.

I haven't run this daemon in a while, but I believe it was functioning as expected on OSX Mountain Lion. The man page for launchd.plist implies this should work. Was there a change around the EnvironmentVariables key in Yosemite?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I see `TEST=some value` in the log. I also see a `PATH=` line that matches the expected one, but I *also* see a default `PATH`, so I suspect that launchctl is just injecting its own `PATH` into the environment (rather than setting it with `setenv`). In my tests, though, `/bin` is in the launchctl path.

Comment: @RobNapier If you change "Program" to "printenv" instead of "/usr/bin/printenv" does it still work for you?

Comment: Yeah; seems the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `launchctl` to load the plist into `launchd`:

```
launchctl load -w myjob.plist
```

> **[launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html)** manages processes, both for the system as a whole and for
>   individual users.  The primary and
>        preferred interface to launchd is via the **[launchctl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/launchctl)**(1) tool which (among other options) allows the user
>        or administrator to load and unload jobs.